# Why does page refreshes when it is on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, backbone.js, save, refresh

I have this code:

```
        racunTemp.save({}, {
            success: function (model, response) {
                stavkeTempCollection.each(function (item) {
                    item.set('RacunID', response.RacunID);
                    item.set('RacunStavkaID', null)
                    item.save();
                });

                stavkeTempCollection.reset();
                viewStavkeTemp.$el.empty();

            }
            });
```

and it works. But when I start the application from my VS2012 platform the code doesn't refresh the page. When I publish it on the IIS server it refreshes the page and slowing down my app. What is the difference? How can I prevent page to refresh?

Comment: Pretty hard to make any meaningful suggestion from your description of the problem, but one fundamental difference between your default VS2012 setup and IIS is that the former by default uses the built-in web server (e.g., http://127.0.0.1/index.aspx), whereas the latter is using IIS, typically via a virtual directory (e.g., http://127.0.0.1/MyApp/index.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for trying. Still doesn't work. Actually, it brakes on "success" is saves the racunTemp.save({} and than just refresh the page.

Comment: I made mistake few rows before I put "window.history.back();" this part of code functioned differently on VS platform than on IIS server.